# preg_match() include "-"

Tags: php

I have already tried to include - in code but I always have problem

What is the correct way to include this character "-" in

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\. ]*$/", $home)
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape it (`\-`), or make it the first charater inside `[]`.

Comment: @meagar: C#?? there are some differences in the regex syntax supported by different languages (even though in this case it is the same), so I think you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @meagar: i know of no regex dialects that would have a syntax for escaping you describe. `[a\-z]` matches all lowercase characters.

Comment: @justsomebody `[-a-z]` and `[a-z-]` both match `-` and `a-z`. You don't have to escape it unless it's ambiguous.

Comment: @meagar yes, you can make it stand for itself inside a character class if you put it first or last.  but there's no amount of backslashes you could put in front of the dash to make it non-special if it's not at those positions.  *You need to escape it (\-)* is wrong.

Comment: @justsomebody I'm sorry but you're demonstrably wrong. The correct amount of backslash is to make it "non-special" is 1. `[a\-z]` matches only three characters, `'a'`, a literal `'-'`, or `'z'`. It is not equivalent to `[a-z]`, it's equivalent to `[-az]` or `[az-]`. Your claim, "`[a\-z]` matches all lower case characters", is wrong, at least in PHP and JavaScript's "regex dialects", and ever other dialect *I've* heard of. Just look at the answers posted below, and the answers posted in the linked duplicate, and virtually any other of the dozens of duplicate questions.

Comment: @meagar you are correct.  i don't know when this capability appeared but it's even in perl-5.20.0.  sorry about spreading BS. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside character classes, `-` signs need to be escaped like this:

```
!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\. \-]*$/", $home);
```

Also, you can drop `A-Z` from the character class and add the `i` flag to the regex like this:

```
!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\. \-]*$/i", $home);
```

Comment: Your hyphen is the last character in the character class: there's no need to escape it in that case. See the linked question for further details.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario interesting - I didn't know that. Thanks for telling  me

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php):

> If a minus character is required in a class, it must be escaped with a
>   backslash or appear in a position where it cannot be interpreted as
>   indicating a range, typically as the first or last character in the
>   class.